# Secant Method with MVT

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, secant

Suppose $(x_k)$ is produced by the secant method applied to $f(x)$. We obtain the
following identity using the mean value theorem

(a) $ξ − x_{k+1} = ξ − x_k −[f'(η_k)/f'(θ_k) ](ξ − x_k)$
for where $η_k$ is between $xk$ and $ξ$, and
θk is between $x_k$ and $x_{k−1}$.

(b) $ξ − x_{k+1} = ξ − x_k +[f'(η_k)/f''(θ_k) ](ξ − x_k)$ 
for where $ηk$ is between $x_k$ and $ξ$, and
θk is between $x_k$ and $x_{k−1}$.

(c) $ξ − x_{k+1} = −
(ξ − x_k)^2 
f
''(η_k)
/2f
'
(x_k)$
for where $η_k$ is between $x_k$ and $ξ$.

(d) $ξ − x_{k+1} = ξ − x_k +
[f
'
(η_k)
/f
'
(θ_k) ](ξ − x_k)^3$
for where $η_k$ is between $x_k$ and $ξ$, and
$θ_k$ is between $x_k$ and $x_{k−1}$.

Comment: Okay... what do you need?

Comment: That's nice.  So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 
$$
x_{k+1}=x_k-f(x_k)\frac{x_k-x_{k-1}}{f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})}
$$
you get
$$
 ξ-x_{k+1}=ξ-x_k-(ξ-x_k)\frac{f(ξ)-f(x_k)}{ξ-x_k}\frac{x_k-x_{k-1}}{f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})}
$$
which should help you to apply the mean value theorem in the relevant places.